# MVC - Application Assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**Question:**

If I have multiple projects in one solution is it still considered a single assembly?

Background Information:
I'm aware the 'MyApplication/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs' file exists. Further, I confirmed that when I:

1. Add a project to the solution.
2. Appropriately reference the newly added project.
3. Lastly, Build the solution.

The 'MyApplication/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs' file has not changed. This leaves me to believe, and please correct me if I'm wrong that I'll have met the demand.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Each project is compiled into one assembly in your case. The assemblyinfo.cs file (for each project) should not change at all when you compile anything. Also, that file's *name* is not important at all; it's the global attributes inside it that cause various properties of the *assembly being created* to be set. That file's name and location are simply a convention.

Comment: Thank you. I see so each project would be considered it's own assembly then, gotcha.